# split & concat string from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, concatenation

From dataframe, 
I want to split from (col1) the number before first symbol `|` into `a` list, the second number after that into `b` list and string from(col1), (text1), (text2), (text3) into `text` list

```
col1       | text1     | text2           | text3
1|6|Show   | us the    | straight way    | null
109|2|I    | worship   | not that        | which ye worship
```

the output that I expected

`a = [1, 109]
 b = [6, 2]
 text = [‘Show us the straight way’, ‘I worship not that which ye worship’]`

what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is straightforward assuming col1 has 3 pipe-separated elements throughout.

```
a,b,C = zip(*df.col1.str.split('|'))
D =  df.drop('col1', 1).agg(lambda x: ' '.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)

c = [c + ' ' + d for c,d in zip(c,D)]
```

```
print(a)
('1', '109')

print(b)
('6', '2')

print(c)
['Show us the straight way', 'I worship not that which ye worship']
```

Note that `a` and `b` is a collection of strings, you can map them to numeric with

```
a, b = map(pd.to_numeric, (a,b))
```

...to get arrays of integers.

---

To handle the generic case of col1 having any number of values, you will need to

```
v = df.col1.str.split('|', expand=True)
m = v.applymap(str.isdigit)
a,b,*_ = v[m].T.agg(lambda x: x.dropna().tolist(), axis=1)

print(a)
['1', '109']

print(b)
['6', '2']
```

`C` can be computed similarly:

```
C = v[~m].agg(lambda x: x.dropna().str.cat(sep=' '), axis=1).tolist()
```

and then small `c` can be computed as before.

Comment: @Ruzannah Thanks for accepting, please also consider upvoting the answer, tia :-)

Comment: i really appreciate, but sorry for my newbie respon  